# How to get my program to Validate the Date entered and move onto the next line of code

Tags: java, arrays, validation, date, netbeans

so I'm fairly new to Java and I'm trying to get the user to input a date they carried out a fuel transaction. I want to check that the date is valid before allowing them to move onto the next line. When I run the code here it doesn't do anything no matter what I enter and the program does not end. Wondering does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, Thanks.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

String[] FuelTransaction = new String [100];


   Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter the Date of the Fuel Transaction in dd/mm/yyyy Format:  ");
   String Date = scanner.nextLine();

    if (validDate(Date))
   {
       System.out.println("The Date of the Fuel Transaction was "+ Date);
   }
   else
   {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Date");
   }




   System.out.println("Enter the Number of Litres of Fuel Purchased: ");
   String litres = scanner.nextLine();
   System.out.println("You Purchased " + litres + " Litres of Fuel");

   System.out.println("Enter the Cost per Litre of Fuel:  £");
   String cost = scanner.nextLine();
   System.out.println("The Cost per Litre of Fuel was: £" + cost);





   System.out.println ("Records Updated Successfully, Would you like to Log another Fuel Transaction? " +
           " If so, Please Enter y");
   String newLog = scanner.nextLine();



   String filepath = ("TransactionDetails.txt");


   newFill(Date,litres,cost,filepath);
}


public static boolean validDate (String Date) {

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");   
Date validFuel = null;
df.setLenient(false);

try {
        validFuel = df.parse(Date);
        return true;

}

catch (Exception e)
    {   
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: When I run your code, it prompts me for a date, and when I give it one in the required format (e.g. `12/12/2012`), it prints "The Date of the Fuel Transaction was 12/12/2012" as expected.  Can you be more explicit about exactly what input you're giving your program, and the expected vs actual output?

Comment: Even when `setLenient(false)`, the [`parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method doesn't fully validate the input, since the javadoc says: *The method may not use the entire text of the given string.* --- You need to use [`parse(String, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) to also validate no extraneous text after the date value. --- Better to use the newer Java 8 Time API, i.e. a `LocalDate` and a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Yes sorry I'm not being too clear its just if i type for example "s" the program just prompts me for another line of code instead of saying invalid date and asking for the date again.

Comment: @Andreas How would I go about implementing one of the newer API? Thanks

Comment: @shan468 You may start by going through [the tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). I too recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome.

Comment: For repeating the prompt in case of an invalid date you need a loop. It’s explained in many places. Use your search engine.

Answer (score 2):

## Case matters

> newFill(Date,litres,cost,filepath);

`Date` is the name of a class, not a reference to an object. Java code is case-sensitive. And Java has conventions: Class names have initial uppercase letter, and object references have initial lowercase letter.

So name your variable `date`, not `Date`.

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### Parse

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Define a formatting pattern to match your input string.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse.

```
String input = "23/01/2019" ;  // January 23, 2019
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

To react to faulty input, trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html). Surround your parsing line with a try-catch.

```
    try
    {
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input , f );
    } catch ( DateTimeException e )
    {
        System.out.println ( e );
        // … handle faulty input …
        // You will likely need a loop. Search Stack Overflow for many many such examples.
    }
```

### Generate text

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;  // Generates text in standard ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DD.
```

Generate text in localized format.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter formatterCAfr = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = ld.format( formatterCAfr ) ;
```

> mercredi 23 janvier 2019